# Convert Time in Eastern time zone and print it in formal time format without GMT-4

Tags: python, timezone, gmt

time_string="1569834192" #in epoch format.
I want to convert it in "US/Eastern" timezone.
But The output I get is as follows:
2019-09-30 14:33:12-04:56
I want exact time instead of this -04:56

my code:
time_string="1569834192"
print datetime.fromtimestamp(time_string, tz= pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

output:
2019-09-30 14:33:12-04:56

time_string="1569834192"
print datetime.fromtimestamp(time_string, tz= pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

2019-09-30 14:33:12-04:56

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 code:

```
import pytz

from datetime import datetime

time_string = 1569834192
us_western = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(time_string, us_western))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(time_string, us_western).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Outputs:

```
2019-09-30 05:03:12-04:00
2019-09-30 05:03:12
```